# GhostLab alternative, testing website multiple devices

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web-browser, web-server, web

I am looking for software to testing websites on multiple devices, with the following features:

- Browser sync in all devices
- Automatic testing using selenium/protractor/apium
- Easy to use for non tech people

I like [GhostLab](http://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) and [Muir](http://labs.iqfoundry.com/), but it fails sometimes and it is unable to do automatic testing. What alternatives are there?

Comment: Question edited following the rules. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, reopened. Not sure if it's sufficient for *good* answers, though. For example: What kind of tests should be applied? But as I'm not active in that context I cannot say whether that might be clear for those who are ;)